# ListView only displaying first item in arraylist

Tags: java, android, listview

List View is only displaying the first item in the data. How do I make it display all the data in the array list. I think its because I am using the the same key in the map bur how do I change that and make it appear. Any help is appreciated.

```
package menu.saryal.example.com.menu;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

import java.util.ArrayList;


/**
 * A placeholder fragment containing a simple view.
 */
public class ItemOrderedFragment extends Fragment {

    private ArrayAdapter<String> itemTitle;
    public final static String  EXTRA_TEXT = "menu.saryal.example.com.menu";

    public ItemOrderedFragment getThisItemOrderedFragment() {
        return thisItemOrderedFragment;
    }

    ItemOrderedFragment thisItemOrderedFragment = this;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_item_ordered, container, false);

        final MenuDbHelper dbHandler = new MenuDbHelper(this.getActivity());
        ArrayList<menuDescription> data = dbHandler.readData();

        // Get a reference to the ListView, and attach this adapter to it.
        ListView listView = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.fragment_item_ordered_list_view);


      ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> albumsList;
        albumsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

        // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
        for(menuDescription x:data){
            map.put("Title", x.getTitle());
            map.put("Description", x.getDescription());
        }
        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        albumsList.add(map);

        ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                this.getActivity(),
                albumsList,
                R.layout.list_item_with_image,
                new String[] { "Title", "Description"},
                new int[] {R.id.list_item_with_image_text_view, R.id.recepit_cost_text_view });
        if (data.size()>0){
            listView.setAdapter(adapter);
        }

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long l) {
                String title = itemTitle.getItem(position);
                menuDescription item = dbHandler.findByTitle(title);
                String cost_string = "" + item.getCost();
                String totalCost_string = "" + item.totalCost;
                String totalOrder_string = "" + item.getTotalOrder();
                String[] transfer_data = {item.getTitle(),item.getDescription(),cost_string,totalCost_string,totalOrder_string,item.getImage()};
                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), EditDetailPage.class);
                intent.putExtra(EXTRA_TEXT, transfer_data);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
        dbHandler.close();
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: `for(menuDescription x:data){` you need to create a new map and add it to the array in this loop

Answer (score 2):

That's because you are actually only adding one `HashMap` to the `ArrayList`.

```
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> albumsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

for(menuDescription x:data){
    //prepare new HashMap
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put("Title", x.getTitle());
    map.put("Description", x.getDescription());
    //add HashMap to ArrayList
    albumsList.add(map);
}
```